# xna update method- why the = sign is acting like +=

Tags: xna

here is my code on projectile class update method.
every fram the previousXposition is being added to the last result instead replacing the last result.
what is the reason and solution to the problem?

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{

    if (Position.X != previousXPosition)
    {
        flightTime += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        Position.X += previousXPosition;
        Position.Y -= previousYPosition;

        previousXPosition = (projectileVelocity.X * flightTime) + 0.5f * (wind * (float)Math.Pow(flightTime, 2));
        previousYPosition = (projectileVelocity.X * flightTime) + 0.5f * (gravity * (float)Math.Pow(flightTime, 2));
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

accumulating 'flightTime' in this manner does not lend itself to velocity changes. Each frame it is assuming the speed for the whole flight has been what it is this particular frame, which isn't the case.

Here is a way I would recommend coding up the projectile flight. Establish 'velocity' as a vector2 whose direction represent the direction the projectile is traveling and whose magnitude represents the speed in units per second that it is traveling.

```
    float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds; // time since last frame only

    // the velocity vector will have a magnitude equiv to units traveled per second.
    float speed = velocity.Length();
    Vector2 windDrag = (Vector2.Negate(velocity) / speed) * (speed * speed * dragCOef);
    Vector2 gravity = Vector2.UnitY * gravCOef;// gravity can be a constant per unit time.

    Vector2 velocityChange = windDrag + gravity;
    velocity += velocityChange * elapsed;// adds just the change of velocity this frame to the overall velocity
    Position += velocity * elapsed;// 'velocity' is distance traveled per second. 'velocity * elapsed' is just distance traveled per frame
```

o

Comment: thanks for the answer but i was wondering why the = sign was acting like += sign in: previousXPosition = which stand for the delta . should i nullify it each time?

Comment: previousXPosition is not the delta. This is because 'flightTime' is not the delta time, but the accumulated time. accumulating time like this usually isn't a good way to go.

Comment: The expressions that you calculate aren't easy to follow. Consider simplifying them or separating them to a few sub expressions to help making it more readable and maintainable.